# log4j integrate with server log and merge with it

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want t save all my info,errors and so on into a text file by using log4j,

To do that i have  configured the log4j and added it to my functions.

The problem here is when i did that this console only shows me :

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      XMLValidationsFunctions objLog4JCoreJavaSample = new XMLValidationsFunctions();
      objLog4JCoreJavaSample.callMeInAppInfo("Log4JCoreJavaSample by Info");

      objLog4JCoreJavaSample.callMeInAppDebug("Log4JCoreJavaSample by Debug");

     }
    }
```

As an example here when i execute that code i want it to show me the info and everything in console like the server does,and externally save it into a .txt file

```
13:15:58,881 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
vfs:/C:/Users/burkilic/EAP-6.3.0/jboss-eap-6.3/standalone/deployments/epo-
transformer.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
13:15:58,881 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
1) Implementation-Title : JAXB Reference Implementation 
13:15:58,881 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
1) Implementation-Version : 2.2.7
13:15:58,881 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
1) Class-Path : jaxb-api.jar
13:15:58,881 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
1) Manifest-Version : 1.0
13:15:58,882 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
1) Specification-Vendor : Oracle Corporation
13:15:58,882 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
1) Created-By : 1.6.0_32-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
13:15:58,882 INFO  [org.docx4j.jaxb.Context] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-
```

The text file is saving the error everything seems fine but i just can not integrate the log file with the all information that i want to save.

Comment: Are you saying you want to log issues to the server's log file?

Comment: Basically i want to make a log file for my program if something happens error,info etc; i want to save it to that file.